# Installing OpenType font

Tags: fonts, latex, libreoffice, gimp, inkscape

I bought a full copy of Hoefler Txt, which is an OpenType font, and I'm trying to install it now on my system (Mint 17). However, the results are inconsistent between programs. Here are the steps I'm taking:

1. Adding the directory `/usr/share/fonts/opentype` (as superuser), and copying the 9 `.otf` files there. All files belong to root, but are readable to everybody.
2. Running `sudo fc-cache -fv`.

However, as I said, the results are inconsistent:

- LibreOffice lists every variant (bold, italic, etc.) as an entirely separate font.
- GIMP lists some variants, but not bold. The plain font itself is bold by default, and can't be made not bold.
- Inkscape lists only a single font, but when I use it, it's bold. I can make it bold-italic, or bold.
- XeTeX also makes it bold, and I can't find a way for it to not be bold.

Does anybody have a clue what's going on? Did I not install the font correctly? Is there a way to check if it's properly installed?

Answer (score 2):

Some programs list the font files like bold, italic, bold italic (given in different `.otf` files) as different fonts.  Other programs let you chose the main font, and automatically select a different source file (font if you will) when you apply attributes like "bold" inside the program.

Some programs may also not be able to interpret certain characteristics in fonts, like hinting (information in the font file for optimal scaling), which may either result in the program ignoring the font or in the font looking different in different programs.

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look in the /etc/fonts configuration directory. Specifically, the configuration files symlinked in /etc/fonts/conf.d could give you an idea how to configure your new font.

PS: I am under the impression best practice would be to install your own fonts into /usr/local/share/fonts. This is probably not important, however, and may vary across distributions.